How to forward to exact path using .htaccess Redirect 301?
I am having an issue in Google Search Console where I need to do a redirect on a page.
The URL is https://example.com/contact/?amp
Using .htaccess... It forwards as it should using the below code but I still get the ?amp .  How do I get it to forward while losing the ?amp  ?

Redirect 301 /contact.php/?amp https://example.com/contact.php

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.
I tried using this:

Redirect 301 /contact.php/?amp https://example.com/contact.php

It forwards but includes the ?amp

The rewriting module offers much more flexibility:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^amp$
RewriteRule ^/?contact\.php$ https://example.com/contact.php [R=301,END,QSD]

The QSD flag is responsible for getting rid of the GET argument ("QueryStringDelete").
